# Change table contents' font size with formattable package from R

Tags: r, fonts, font-size, formattable

Assuming a dataframe as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(week1 = c(30, 74.62, 189.93, 2394.91, 6095.8, 
2.88, 45.49), week2 = c(30, 88.4, 156.14, 2880.4, 5087.41, 7.98, 
44.97), change = structure(c(0, -0.1559, 0.2164, -0.1685, 
0.1982, -0.6391, 0.0114), formattable = list(formatter = "formatC", 
    format = list(format = "f", digits = 2L), preproc = "percent_preproc", 
    postproc = "percent_postproc"), class = c("formattable", 
"numeric"))), row.names = c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7"), class = "data.frame")
```

I have created a table with `formattable` with code below:

```
formattable(df,
            list(~ formatter("span",
                             style = x ~ formattable::style(display = "block",
                                                            "border-radius" = "10px",
                                                            "padding" = "10px",
                                                            "text-align" = "center")),
              week2 = color_tile("white", "orange"),
              week1 = color_tile("white", "orange"),
              `change` = formatter("span",
                 style = ~ style(color = ifelse(`week2` > `week1`, "green", "red"), "font.weight" = "bold", "font.size" = "16px"),
                 ~ icontext(sapply(`change`, function(x) if (x < 0) "arrow-down" else if (x > 0) "arrow-up" else ""), `change`))))
```

Out:

[image]

I'm able to set font sizes for `change` column's values, but now I want to apply this to the whole table including **row names**, how could I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the font-size of the table globaly in the `table.attr` argument.
You can overwrite these settings for certain columns by defining the font-size inside a `formatter` argument. Like you did with the `change` column.

In the example below the table font-size is set to 16px like the `change` column.

```
df <- data.frame(week1 = c(30, 74.62, 189.93, 2394.91, 6095.8, 2.88, 45.49), 
                 week2 = c(30, 88.4, 156.14, 2880.4, 5087.41, 7.98, 44.97), 
                 change = c(0, -0.1559, 0.2164, -0.1685, 0.1982, -0.6391, 0.0114))
rownames(df) <- LETTERS[1:7]

formattable(df,
            list(week2 = color_tile("white", "orange"),
                 week1 = color_tile("white", "orange"),
                 `change` = formatter("span",
                                      style = ~ style(color = ifelse(`week2` > `week1`, "green", "red"), "font.weight" = "bold", "font.size" = "16px"),
                                      ~ icontext(sapply(`change`, function(x) if (x < 0) "arrow-down" else if (x > 0) "arrow-up" else ""), `change`))),
            table.attr = 'style="font-size: 16px;";\"')
```